# How to get file's properties from Windows' registry?

Tags: python, windows, file, registry

I'm trying to get a file type with Python. For example, if I give the code "somearchive.rar" it must return "WinRAR Archive". If I give it "someapplication.exe" it must return "Application", etc...

Basically the text you see when you open a file's properties in Windows, on the "File type" line.

I don't know how to do this, though I think you can do it by looking at the registry or something similar and taking the file's properties (or file's extension properties?) and then keeping only the type, because I saw this code

```
def def_app(estensione):
    class_root = winreg.QueryValue(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, estensione)
    with winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, r'{}\shell\open\command'.format(class_root)) as key:
        command = winreg.QueryValueEx(key, '')[0]
        return shlex.split(command)[0]
```

that looks at the registry and gives you the default application that opens files with the given extension.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-file-extension-in-python/

We have a few ways here.

Comment: File extensions are mere conventions. I could have a plain text file with a .exe extension. That doesn't mean that it's executable. If you want to make assumptions about what a file is based on its extension then you'd be better off using a dictionary of known extensions (as keys) and their assumed types as the dictionary values. Also, think about portability. Your code could never work on a Unix type of platform

Comment: @DarkKnight: The Windows registry *is* effectively a dictionary like you described and it makes sense to try to use it for this purpose.

Comment: @DarkKnight at the end I created a dictionary with a list of known extensions and names thanks to the library that Sayid Munawar suggested. I didn't have any list of known files, and if I created it I'm sure I would have forgot some files. For now what I'm trying to make it's only for Windows, but I think it could work with a Unix platform too.

Comment: @martineau yes, it would be very useful, but for now I don't really know where to look for these files informations. I will see if it's possible.

Comment: @Shashwat the ways listed there are to get the file extension and name, but I want that it gives me the file **type based on the extension**.

Comment: Kikkiu: The layout of the Windows registry is well-known. I'm sure you can find something that tells you how to look-up the information related to a given file extension. Just to get you started, type `assoc /?` at a Windows command-line prompt. Another very useful command-line utility is `regedit` which will allow to explore the contents of the whole registry. Use it and take a look at what's under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Comment: @martineau Microsoft themselves define the Windows Registry as a database. Nonetheless, if the OP wants to limit the code to a Windows platform then I guess it might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I found out how to do it... This code checks the file type (or association) by looking in the Windows' registry (the same as opening regedit, going in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` and then looking at the keys in there, as the user @martineau suggested):

```
rawcom = os.popen("assoc ."+command[len(command)-1]).read().split("=")
```

It is already split, so I can do `rawcom[1]` and get the file type easily.
If there isn't a file association in the Windows' registry, it checks the file type using this code that I found:

```
def get_file_metadata(path, filename, metadata):
    sh = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Shell.Application', 0)
    ns = sh.NameSpace(path)
    file_metadata = dict()
    item = ns.ParseName(str(filename))
    for ind, attribute in enumerate(metadata):
        attr_value = ns.GetDetailsOf(item, ind)
        if attr_value:
            file_metadata[attribute] = attr_value
    return file_metadata

if __name__ == '__main__':
    folder = direc
    filename = file
    metadata = ['Name', 'Size', 'Item type', 'Date modified', 'Date created']
    proprietà = get_file_metadata(folder, filename, metadata)
```

It does exactly what I was trying to do at the start, getting the file type as if I was opening the file's properties in the Windows explorer. With this I put the file metadata in a dictionary and then get only the "Item type" value.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this library can help: [filetype](https://pypi.org/project/filetype/)

Example:

```
In [1]: import filetype

In [2]: kind = filetype.guess('/Users/ayik/Pictures/Archive.rar')

In [3]: print(f'MIME type: {kind.mime}')
MIME type: application/x-rar-compressed
```

from then you can map the MIME types to your desired types

Comment: I already use mime and magic (the same for this library) to get the file type, but it's not exactly what i wanted. In that page there is a list of known extensions, though, so it can help. I'm not going to mark this as solution for now as it doesn't exactly do what I want to do.